# Moving characters in 2d array

Tags: c

I tried to create a 8 x 8 checkers game. I am trying to move the hyphen ' _ ' in the 2d array to select the character 'X' that I want. I have created the if statement for detecting the hyphen ' _ ' but seem that my code isn't working, I really need help. I am new to programming.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void gameboard(char board[8][8])
{

 int x, y;

  for(x=0; x<8; x++)
  {
   for(y=0; y<8; y++)
    {
    printf("=---=");
    }
    printf("\n\n");

    for(y=0;y<8;y++)
    {
    printf("| %c |",board[x][y]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
  }


  for(x=0;x<8;x++)
  {
  printf("=---=");
  }


}

void character(char board[8][8])
{
 int x,y;

 for(x=0;x<8;x++){
   for(y=0;y<8;y++){
    if(x<3){

       if(x%2 == 0){
              if(x%2 == 0){
              board[x][y] = 'O';

              }
              if(y%2==1){
              board[x][y]= ' ';

              }
       }
       if(x%2 == 1){
              if(y%2 == 0){
              board[x][y] = ' ';
               }
              if(y%2 ==1){
             board[x][y]= 'O';

              }
       }

    }

    if((x==3) || (x==4)){
    board[x][y] = ' ';
    } 

    if(x>4)
    {

           if(x%2 == 0){
                  if(y%2 == 0){
                  board[x][y] = 'X';

                  }
                  if(y%2 ==1){
                  board[x][y]= ' ';

                  }
           }

           if(x%2 == 1){
                  if(y%2 == 0){
                  board[x][y] = ' ';

                   }
                  if(y%2 ==1){
                  board[x][y]= 'X';

                  }
           }

          if(x==5 && y ==1)
          { 
          if(x%2 == 1){
                  if(y%2 == 1){
                  board[x][y] = '_';
                  }
                 }
            }        
    }

    }
   }

}


void playgame(char board[8][8])
{

 int x=0, y=0, a, b, c=0,input;
 char token;


 printf("\n\n---START GAME---\n");



     if(token == '_')
  {
    printf("Please select your token : ");
    }

 for(a=0; a<8; a++)
 {
  for(b=0; b<8; b++)
   {
    if(board[a][b] == token & c == 0)
    {
     x = a;
     y = b;
     c++;
     }
    }
 }

  printf("1 to go right\n");
  printf("2 to go left\n");
  printf("3 to go up left\n");
  printf("4 to go up right\n");
  printf("5 to go down left\n");
  printf("6 to go down right\n");
  printf("7 to select token\n");
  fflush(stdin);
  scanf("%i", &input);

   if(input == 1)
   {
    board[x][y+2] = token;
    y++;
    }
   else if(input == 2)
    {
     board[x][y-2] = token;
     y--;
     }
    else if(input == 3)
     {
     board[x-1][y-1] = token;
     x--;
     y--;
     }
     else if(input == 4)
     {
     board[x-1][y+1] = token;
     x--;
     y++;
     }
     else if(input == 5)
     {
      board[x+1][y-1] = token;
      x++;
      y--;
     }
     else if(input == 6)
     {
      board[x+1][y+1] = token;
      x++;
      y++;
      }
      else
      {
      board[x][y] = token;
      }
}


int main()
{

  char bx[8][8];


  gameboard(bx);

  playgame(bx);

 return 0;

}
```

Comment: Your variables are not initialized. When you ask it to print `printf("| %c |",board[x][y]);` what do you expect to print?

Comment: @BarmakShemirani huh..? That should print the characters 'O' and 'X'.

Comment: You declare `char bx[8][8]`, then you print `printf("| %c |",board[x][y])`. That means you are printing uninitialized variables. For example `bx[0][0]` will have some random value. Initialize your variables, then simplify your code by removing all the decorative stuff out of it so people can understand it.

Comment: Related, similar problem with `if(token == '_')` in `playgame`; `token` us unintiailized. Unrelated,  stop lying to the compiler. `gameboard` *says* it returns `int`, but in reality does no such thing.

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize the array, then use `switch` statement to calculate the new position based on input.

Save the old position and swap the content of the new cell with that of the old cell in the saved position.

```
int main()
{
    char board[8][8];
    int x, y;
    for (x = 0; x < 8; x++)
        for (y = 0; y < 8; y++)
            board[x][y] = '.';
    board[0][0] = '_';

    int xpos = 0;
    int ypos = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        system("cls||clear");
        //print board
        for (y = 0; y < 8; y++)
        {
            for (x = 0; x < 8; x++)
                printf("%c", board[x][y]);
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("Menu\n 1 left \n2 right \n3 up \n4 down \n");

        int savex = xpos;
        int savey = ypos;
        int move = 0;
        scanf("%d", &move);
        char c;
        while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);

        switch (move)
        {
        case 1: if (xpos > 0) xpos--; break;
        case 2: if (xpos < 7) xpos++; break;
        case 3: if (ypos > 0) ypos--; break;
        case 4: if (ypos < 7) ypos++; break;
        }

        //swap position:
        board[savex][savey] = '.';
        board[xpos][ypos] = '_';
    }
    return 0;
}
```